# Addition in $\mathbb{C}$ justification

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a rather rudimentary question, but I cannot seem to rigorously justify it other than appealing to intuition.

Suppose I am doing arithmetic in $\mathbb{C}$, and I come to 
$$ 
\frac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2}.
$$ 
(For simplicity, assume that at least one of $a$ or $b$ is non-zero). This is certainly equal to 
$$\frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} + \left(\frac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}\right)i.$$
What is the justification for this step other than "definition of complex addition"? Addition in $\mathbb{C}$ states to add the real components and the complex components but it doesn't seem that we're doing that. Instead, we're "applying the inverse" of $a^2 + b^2$ and using the fact that multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative. If I wanted to rigorously justify this step by step, I might write: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{a-bi}{a^2 + b^2} & = (a - bi)(a^2 + b^2)^{-1} & & \text{def of inverse in $\mathbb{C}$; commut of mult} \\
& = a(a^2 + b^2)^{-1} - bi(a^2 + b^2)^{-1} & & \text{distributivity in $\mathbb{C}$} \\
& = \frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} + \frac{-bi}{a^2 + b^2} & & \text{rewrite; associativity of scalar mult in $\mathbb{R}$} \\
& = \frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} + \left(\frac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}\right) i & & \text{associativity of mult in $\mathbb{R}$}
\end{align*}
Are either of these lines of reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about $\Bbb C$ for the moment. How do you prove $\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{x}{z}+\frac{y}{z}$? Your$$\frac{x+y}{z}=(x+y)z^{-1}=xz^{-1}+yz^{-1}=\frac{x}{z}+\frac{y}{z}$$technique (or change the $+$s to $-$ if you like) is the right one; it explains why multiplication's distributivity over addition implies division's behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is the step where you went from $xz^{-1}$ to $\frac{x}{z}$ by definition? Or are we really saying $xz^{-1} = \frac{x}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{z} = \frac{x}{z}$ by the definition of multiplication of fractions?

Comment: @JohnP. Well, how do you *define* division in a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))? I imagine it's $x\div z:=xz^{-1}$. [Consider yourself lucky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) we're working with a field, BTW.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @J.G.: I didn't know about this algebraic structure before. Thank you for sharing it here.